# How to Dispose Object instance when it lost it's reference

Tags: c#, object, reference, destructor

Using C#.

I have a MainFoo class:

```
class MainFoo
{
    private Foo foo;

    public MainFoo()
    {
        this.foo = new Foo();
    }  

    public CreateNewFoo()
    {
        this.foo = new Foo();
    }

    public DoCurrentFoo()
    {
        this.foo.Do();
    }
}
```

A Foo class:

```
class Foo
{
    ~Foo()
    {
        this.DoEnd();
    }

    public void Do() {}

    private void DoEnd() {}
}
```

I want to be able to call the method `DoEnd()` **in Foo** class whenever `private Foo;` get's initialized again. This method `DoEnd()` is private and I would like to keep it that way *(so not accessible from `MainFoo`)*.

Since the same Foo get's initialized again, I though the instance would loose it's reference so it would call destructor. But this gets only called when `MainFoo` instance lost reference.

Question: How to dispose object instance when it lost it's reference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Destructors are not guaranteed to be called at any specific time, or even get called at all. Typically, you should not rely on destructor and should implement IDisposable and call Dispose yourself.

Most conviniently, this can be done with `using(...){ }`.

Getting back to your sample, you can also dispose object on assignment of property (as Jason Watkins suggested), but make sure that it is not used anywhere else.

```
public Foo F
{
    get{return foo;}
    set
    {
        if( foo != null)
            foo.Dispose();
        foo = value;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, it's the [Garbage Collector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973837.aspx)'s job.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228629%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> In C#, garbage collection is handled by the common language runtime (CLR) with similar functionality to that of the JVM. The CLR garbage collector periodically **checks the memory heap for any unreferenced objects**, and releases the resources held by these objects.